# Find closest lat/lng in PHP for an array of input values

Tags: php, arrays, maps

I have code that, for an array of lat/long pairs, finds the nearest lat/long pair from another array:

Input:

`$reference_array`, which is an associative array, where the keys are "labels", and the values are the lat/long of that label. For example, it could match town name to the centroid of the town.

`$input_array`, which is a list of lat/long pairs.

I need to find the label from `$reference_array` that is nearest to each of the points in `$input_array`. I also have a maximum radius, so any nearest point not within that radius is given the "nearest label" of null.

I have code that works - I iterate through each array, compute the distance between each pair, and then record the nearest label (and its distance) for each point in `$input_array`. This works, and is basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589130/find-closest-longitude-and-latitude-in-array), but is not efficient, and my script is timing out with relatively few points. I can't control the size of `$reference_array`, so there are always going to be large amounts of comparisons that need to be performed.

My question - what data structures or algorithms can I use to improve the efficiency of this computation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve the efficiency if at first you check the points is included in the square with side 2 * radius or not. Becouse a comparison operations is much smaller load than the calculation of the distance.